# iPhone GPS distance between two points

Tags: iphone

How to find the distance between from current location to another?

Comment: a useful template is (a) look in SO if the question has been asked before (b) do a web search with your favorite search engine, (c) try the found example by yourself, (d) come here and ask if something is not working or need it explained.

Answer (score 6):

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:doubleLattitude longitude:doubleLongitude];

        double distanceDouble; 

        if([user_Location respondsToSelector:@selector(distanceFromLocation:)])
            distanceDouble = [user_Location distanceFromLocation:location];
        else 
            distanceDouble = [user_Location getDistanceFrom:location];
```

This way you support both OS 4.0 and 3.0 since getDistanceFrom is [deprecated](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW23) now.

In the above example user_Location is also a CLLocation object.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to find the distance between two CLLocations.

```
CLLocationDistance distance = [firstLocation getDistanceFrom:secondLocation];
```

Comment: This method has been deprecated since 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:"current location latitude" longitude:"current location longitude";

    CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:"other latitude" longitude:"other longitude";

    CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
```